# Microstrategy - AddDays

Tags: microstrategy

I need to be able to use the AddDays function to derive the last week from the date column that I have in the dataset.
So, I have delivery_date of 3/21/2018, then I want to derive AddDays('3/21/2018',-7.0) - only that I want to do do this for every row in the dataset. But, the AddDays function only takes a metric. Can you suggest how I can work around this situation?

Thank you in advance,
Abhilash

Answer (score 0):

As usual it depends on what you want to achieve.

If you need an attribute that returns `delivery_date - 7`, just create a new attribute and in the definition of the expression you can put a formula like `[delivery_date] - 7` or use a pass-through function like `ApplySimple` to write the formula for your database (more info [here](https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB39990-How-to-use-ApplySimple-to-create-attribute-form-to)).

Note: If you do this, you need to do the form expression with the formula (or the ApplySimple) only for the forms mapped on the fact table, the forms mapped on the lookup table (your Day dimension table) should be without formula, otherwise parent level will returns wrong values. Also if you don't a lookup for this new attribute create an alias or enable -Attribute Role Recognization [more here](https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB6197-How-do-Attribute-Roles-Work-in-MicroStrategy).

If you need to calculate metric values for `delivery_date - 7`, then in that case you need to use a transformation metric. You will need to create a `minus 7 days` or `same day previous week` transformation, then associate it to the Delivery Date attribute and create the needed metrics. The last week transformation is included in the MicroStrategy Tutorial project.